# абсолютное позиционирование элемента

Tags: css, position

на что влияет position: relative  у предка для абсолютного элемента. в чем разница: предок  relative  или нет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если родитель позиционирован статически, то есть `static` (позиционирование по умолчанию), то текущий элемент будет искать родителей выше. В крайнем случае он дойдет до `<body>` и будет позиционироваться относительно всей страницы.